# Is There an Open Source Equivalent for Mathematica's SeriesCoefficient Function?

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, sagemath

I am exploring options for using computer to extract the coefficient of $x^n$ from the Taylor series expansion of a function of $x$, where $n$ is kept as a symbolic entity. While Mathematica offers a function called `SeriesCoefficient` that achieves this, I am in search of an open source alternative that offers similar functionality. I looked into SageMath and SymPy. They do not seem to have this function. If you fix $n$ as a number, these two can get you the coefficient of $x^n$, but not when you keep $n$ as a symbol. Does anyone know of any open source software package that can perform this task?

Comment: Hello. Have you read [this](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/constructions/calculus.html#power-series)? Particularly the "maxima subsystem" bit? I'm not an expert in Sage or Maxima but that seems to be the sort of thing you're talking about right?

Comment: I have used sagemath for this sort of things. You must specify the value of $n$ for it to work. You can get closed form formula for an integer $n$ when its kept a symbol.

Comment: Now I'm not sure what you're asking. Don't you want a symbolic expression for the Taylor series expansion? Isn't that what's produced by the `maxima(f).powerseries(x,0)._sage_()` snippet?

Comment: Oh. I see. Sorry I missed that part. Can you write a brief answer and I accept it?

Comment: [Reduce CAS, free and online](http://www.reduce-algebra.com/web-reduce/about.php?start).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/) can do this, and in particular this functionality can be accessed in SageMath using the Maxima subsystem as described briefly [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/constructions/calculus.html#power-series): if `f` is an expression involving `x`, then `maxima(f).powerseries(x,0)._sage_()` will produce a symbolic form of the Taylor series expansion around $0$.